# Do we need a flag/close option for questions asking for people to befriend or play with them?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, closing, flags

I've seen quite a few questions asking for people to play with someone, add them to their friends list, or most recently, [help them out in-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214323/need-a-modder-to-help-me-out).  I used the Very Low Quality flag on that question, but maybe something should be added to "close for another reason..." options.

The existing options came fairly close, but we might could use a "This question is asking for friends to play with, not an answerable question." or even a very general "This is not a question." option in there somewhere for cases like this one.  What do you think?

Or should I have not flagged the question at all, and simply waited for enough high-rep users to VTC?

Comment: I'd flag similar questions as off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

We won't need an extra flag option for these questions and no you've done nothing wrong by flagging the question.

If you see a post that doesn't belong here but you don't have enough reputation to cast a close vote, just flag it. If it falls under one of the predefined off-topic categories you'll be able to select these if you click on "This question should be closed". If you feel like the question should be closed for another reason just create a custom flag with a comment.

This specific question definitely didn't belong here and it had to be closed ASAP but I don't see questions like this all too often so I think an extra flagging option would be overkill.

The only thing that comes to my mind is adding a line to the close reason of software hardware recommendation. Basically saying that requesting out-of-game resources (Help from another player) is off-topic. But then again there are some exceptions
 to out-of-game content.

Comment: +1 - The type of question that the OP is talking about isn't common enough to warrant a new close reason (or updating an old one). The custom close reasons don't cover every off-topic reason (and aren't meant to) - only the most common ones.